# Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager can't read config sections containing encrypted passwords in applicationHost.config

Tags: iis-7, applicationhost, config

I have some sites in IIS7 that are configured to run as domain users (MYDOMAIN\someuser).

I'm using the Microsoft.Web.Administration namespace to scan my server configuration, but it's throwing an exception when I hit one of these "impersonator" sites:

```
using (ServerManager sm = new ServerManager()) {
    foreach (Site site in sm.Sites) {
        foreach (Application app in site.Applications.Reverse()) {
            foreach (VirtualDirectory vdir in app.VirtualDirectories.Reverse()) {
                var config = app.GetWebConfiguration();
                foreach (var locationPath in config.GetLocationPaths()) {
                    // error occurs in GetLocationPaths()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The actual error message is:

```
COMException was unhandled 
Filename: \\?\C:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config 
Line number: 279
Error: Failed to decrypt attribute 'password' because the keyset does not exist
```

It appears that IIS is storing the MYDOMAIN\someuser password encrypted in applicationHost.config, which is great in terms of security - but I have no idea how to get the ServerManager to decrypt this.

Any tips on how I can either allow ServerManager to decrypt this, or just tell IIS to store the passwords in plain text?

This is on IIS7 under Windows 7 RC, by the way.

Answer (score 0):

IIS uses encryption for attributes that are marked as "encrypted=true" in its schema. Also in its schema it defines the provider to use for the encryption (See C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\schema\IIS_Schema.xml), in the case of password inside the Virtual Directory it uses the AesProvider which is defined in the section configProtectedData inside ApplicationHost.config.

In there you will be able to see the KeyContainerName that you need to grant permissions for whatever account you want to be able to decrypt, which for security reasons, by default only includes Administrators.

This leads me to my question, if your code is failing I would guess that you have granted access to ApplicationHost.config to a user that is not an Administrator, is that the case?
If that is, then I would suggest making sure this is not going to open security risks for your environment.